# Simple DNS configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, forwarding, zones, zoneedit

I am trying to configure my computer to run its own DNS server. The only thing I want to do is to forward all requests for `my.example.com` to `my-staging.example.com`. So, when I would use a phone, who's DNS is my computer, the requests would also be redirected.

I can't seem to figure out what exactly should the zone file contain, could anyone please help ?

I tried:

```
example.com. 7200   IN SOA ns1.example.com. ( 
                         2008010402 
                         15 
                         3600 
                         3000000 
                         86400 )
                    IN NS example.com
my.example.com.     IN A   213.144.138.203
```

but does not seem to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to use a CNAME record to setup the alias. Once you have yoru basic headers and ruls in place, you'll need something like this:

```
my   IN   CNAME my-staging.example.com.
```

(Note trailing dot is important.)

However since this dns file will be hosting the DNS for example.com, you also need a way to resolve the my-staging address. You can do this by seting a static A record or by using an alternate name if it has one.

```
my-staging   IN   A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

or

```
my-staging   IN   CNAME alternate.dns.name.for.mystagingexample.com.
```